# Why is this sound device recognized but no software can record with it?

Tags: sound, usb, microphone

I recently bought an [Alesis iO4](http://www.alesis.com/io4), a 4 microphone USB input device, which, [according to this site](http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/current_audio_gear#alesis_-_io4_usb_-_class_compliant_11_or_20) works under Linux "completely", and was tested using Ubuntu 9.04. So I thought it was a good bet it would work with my 12.10 Ubuntu laptop.

When I connect it by USB to my laptop, it is recognized under the sound settings, and if I speak into the microphones I can see a response:

[image: sound input]

So far so good. However, in [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), when I press "record", I see no response whatsoever. My main concern is Audacity, but I tried also using Ubuntu's "Sound Recorder" utility, and it also showed no response in its level meter when I spoke into the mike, so I think this isn't just an Audacity problem.

I looked into Audacity's preferences, and under `Host` in the `Interface` section, the only option is `ALSA`. Under `Device` in the `Recording` section, there are four options. `HDA:Intel` is my on-board sound card. I'm not sure what the difference between `pulse`, `default`, and `sysdefault` is, but in any case, selecting any of them does not seem to change anything.

[image: audacity settings]

Why is my sound device seen by the OS but not by Audacity (or any other software)?

How do I set it up so that Audacity takes input from this device?

---

***Update:*** According to [a very helpful person on the Audacity forums](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=70920), the problem I'm reporting here is most likely caused by [a bug in ALSA](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45813). The current version of ALSA in the Ubuntu repositories does not seem to contain the necessary patch, so I'm hoping it will be updated soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [very helpful advice on the Audacity forums](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=70920), and also a little lucky experimentation, I have discovered a workable solution.

The key is that the iO4 **must** be plugged in *before* the laptop boots. If I try to plug it in any other time after that, it does not work as described in the question. If I plug it in before booting, then it's very easy. Audacity can select the device independentaly of any other sound settings and will record all four channels.

I believe this might be a bug in that a USB device should be able to work even when plugging in after booting the computer (all my other USB devices work this way). But I will file a bug report for that. For the time being, I can at least use my device as intended, so the issue as originally outlined can be considered closed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with Audacity getting your mic's input.. I had the same issue with Teamspeak and still do with Skype. Basically you need to play around with the host, and usually under Recording using the default device works. :)